# Regular expressions in scala, find a value corresponding to a key

Tags: regex, scala

I'm new to Scala and I'm not really sure how regex works.

I want to extract a value from a string.

```
String = "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3"
```

I need to find out what is *value2*.

Can I do it with regex? Any pointers?

So far I tried this but it's not working:

```
"/key2=([^&]*)/"
```

Comment: Please show the entire relevant code.

Comment: A hint: you do not need `/`, the `"key2=([^&]*)"` might be all you need.

Comment: Thanks that worked.

Comment: I posted an answer below, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to match what you need using `match` and an unanchored regex:

```
var str = "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3"
val pattern = """key2=([^&]*)""".r.unanchored
val res = str match {
   case pattern(res) => println(res)
   case _ => "No match"
}
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/b71XCG)

Note that within `match`, the pattern is anchored by default, and in order to find a match anywhere inside a string, you should make your pattern `.unanchored`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do without regex as well. First split using `&` and then using `=`

```
str.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("&")
.map { str => 
  val Array(a, b) = str.split("=") 
  a -> b 
}.toMap.get("key2")
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> str.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("&").map { str => val Array(a, b) = str.split("="); a -> b }.toMap.get("key2")
res23: Option[String] = Some("value2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the desired values into the first match group using following regular expression,

```
^.*?key1=(.+?)(&.*?)*$
^.*?key2=(.+?)(&.*?)*$
^.*?key3=(.+?)(&.*?)*$
...
```

It depends on the fact that `&` does not appear anywhere in your `values`. You can experiment with it some more - [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/Bd9Sws/1)

Now, lets move to required Scala,

```
def findValueForKeyI(i: Int, str: String): Option[String] = {
  val regex = ("^.*?key" + i + "=(.+?)(&.*?)*$").r
  val matcher = regex.pattern.matcher(str)
  matcher.matches match {
    case true => Some(matcher.group(1))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Now lets try in Scala console,

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def findValueForKeyI(i: Int, str: String): Option[String] = {
  val regex = ("^.*?key" + i + "=(.+?)(&.*?)*$").r
  val matcher = regex.pattern.matcher(str)
  matcher.matches match {
    case true => Some(matcher.group(1))
    case _ => None
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

findValueForKeyI: (i: Int, str: String)Option[String]

scala> val str = "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3"
str: String = key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3

scala> findValueForKeyI(1, str)
res24: Option[String] = Some(value1)

scala> findValueForKeyI(2, str)
res25: Option[String] = Some(value2)

scala> findValueForKeyI(3, str)
res26: Option[String] = Some(value3)

scala> findValueForKeyI(4, str)
res27: Option[String] = None
```